# AIR iOS stage video - prevent the zoom effect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm using stageVideo with AIR for iOS successfully but have noticed that when the video is started it scales itself up fro 0% to 100% centrally (similar to how an iOS app would launch).

Would anyone know if it's possible to prevent this scaling up (zoom effect) and just display the video at the correct 100% size.

Thanks,

Mark

This is the code I'm using to add the video:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
ns = new NetStream(nc);
ns.client = this;

sv = stage.stageVideos[0];
sv.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, onRender);
sv.attachNetStream(ns);

private function onRender(e:StageVideoEvent):void {
sv.removeEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, onRender);
sv.viewPort = new Rectangle(110,133,800,450);
ns.play("urlToVideo.mp4");
}
```

Comment: It seems to be a bug affecting AIR on iOS 5.1: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4332059

Comment: You could try a little hack. Play and then pause the video, with some Sprite in front of it to hide the `StageVideo` layer. Wait a second, then play the video again and remove the cover.